# How to answer a question: detailed or brief then edit? And if question is closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Ok

So so the scenario is I see a question and start typing out my answer, and want to answer it well. At some point, several minutes into this I get a notification that the question has been closed and no new answers can be posted.

All my time gone to waste. When I tried posting a "placeholder" answer just now (in meta) it got deleted on me with 4 negative rep.

So how exactly do you expect me to avoid the above situation?

1. Should I be more careful first before answering the question to check if it is a duplicate before attempting to answer? (often the reason it gets closed)
2. Should I type a "summary" answer then edit it. Not a meaningless placeholder, but just a quick "summary" of the solution I am about to type in full?
3. May I suggest a "grace" period to submit an answer if a question is closed. Maybe on the alert you get 15 seconds to hit submit? (Someone suggested that existed before but has been taken away).

Comment: "So how exactly do you expect me to avoid the above situation?" - not try to answer questions that need to be closed instead? Bad questions not being answered is not what Stack Overflow is suffering from.

Comment: If it's going to be closed anyway, is there any point in allowing you to write your answer?

Comment: I would agree that if the answer is going to be closed and therefore no one will see the answer, it would be better to let you know. Sure it's frustrating that you've spent 10 minutes typing out an answer, but by telling you via notification it could save you another 10 minutes typing out an answer, that like I've already mentioned, no one will see.

Comment: No, people see answers to closed questions.

Comment: You can simply choose to do what I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753707/using-isset-to-validate-whether-a-user-is-logged-in-on-a-website

Comment: Ok I will edit my question slightly.

Comment: Oh I see you asked the question again yourself then posted your answer

Comment: @Fluffeh: I edited out the noise from your question

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, it's a different question and you lot are a bigoted clique.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, posting a placeholder answer is not the way to go.

Secondly, there is a grace period after a question is closed during which you can post an answer you have started writing. I'm not sure exactly what the conditions are that allow this or block this as I'm not an employee, but it's definitely there. If you're not being allowed to post then you've either exceeded the allotted time or something else is going on.

However, if you are experiencing this a lot then perhaps you have to look more critically at the type of questions you are choosing to answer and ask yourself if they are really on topic or good quality questions **before** deciding to answer. One of the issues we have, on Stack Overflow especially, with low quality questions is that people answer them before they get closed. This encourages the asking of such questions - "It doesn't matter how crap your question is, you'll always get an answer". If fewer (or no) people answered these questions then, maybe, fewer people would ask them.

Comment: No, there is no grace period, and questions are often closed now by just one user claiming it to be a duplicate.

Comment: @CashCow - that's a recent change then, because there always used to be.

Comment: Well I've been burned a few too many times recently

Comment: @ChrisF: There is a grace period, but the UI deactivates the submit button if the question gets closed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I'm never sure how this works because we regularly get questions asking how an answer could be posted to a closed question. Maybe it depends on the browser?

Comment: @ChrisF: Or how handy someone is with the browser developer tools?

Comment: I recall being able to post an answer to a question on Meta that had been closed while I was answering. It is possible that I had to use the debugging tool to reactivate the submit button. It's been a while so I don't remember whether I definitely had to do that.

Comment: @ChrisF Unless something changed, I'm pretty sure the grace period still exists server-side, but you are blocked client side once the question is closed.  If your browser never receives the notification from the server that the post was closed, you will still be able to submit the answer, but if your browser does receive the notification, then the "post your answer" button will be disabled.

Comment: Ok so please give me the link to how I submit it anyway

Comment: I guess there was a reason they disabled the button in HTML to prevent you sending. So personally I see it as a bug, but apparently it is seen as a feature.

Comment: ok so it's a good question then. Edit it and remove all my downvotes with some upvotes. Not that it affects rep but may prevent me asking new questions.

Comment: @CashCow - there's no automatic question block on Meta.

Comment: ok, good to know there is no peer pressure to delete a "bad" question then.