# Is it better to be detailed and if so then should I be rewarded for that?

Tags: support, answers

In [How to read Assembly output generated by Visual C++ 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651166/how-to-read-assembly-output-generated-by-visual-c-2010/) I took the time to create a more detailed response but because I took extra time I got no votes. I really believe I provided a detailed explanation compared to the one that got votes. Is that how it is supposed to work? Is it better to be quick than to be detailed? If it is better to be detailed then is there something I can do to get rewarded for that?

I have seen [Add “What types of questions should I avoid answering?” to the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center). It is actually discussing poor questions and how to improve Stack Overflow to reduce quick answers.

I have also seen [How to answer a question: detailed or brief then edit? And if question is closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270718/how-to-answer-a-question-detailed-or-brief-then-edit-and-if-question-is-closed). It is asking about the situation in which a question is about to be closed.

Neither one discusses the situation where a more detailed answer does not get recognition.

I see that the [How to answer a question: detailed or brief then edit? And if question is closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270718/how-to-answer-a-question-detailed-or-brief-then-edit-and-if-question-is-closed) got a -14. I hope that does not happen to this question. I have avoided contributing to Stack Overflow and if this question gets negative votes then I will certainly be discouraged from contributing in the future.

Comment: You just wait, that's all.

Comment: related: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: "I have avoided contributing" is a weird statement. Does that mean you *knew* answers to unanswered questions but chose not to submit them in trepidation of downvotes or (in your book at least as bad) *no votes*?

Comment: You don't seem to be answering the question, but instead making a comment about two lines in the listing.

Comment: "I have avoided contributing" means I just have not spent time in this site. I have not come here except to get answers, seldom to provide answers. There are many things that discourage me from coming here. Many years ago I contributed much to CodeGuru then I did contribute in MSDN forums. I am now an editor for another site but this site is more discouraging than encouraging.

Comment: Yes in this instance my first sentence was not the best choice.

Answer (score 9):

Just don't assume that votes are proportional to the amount of work you put in writing the answer.  Not the way it works at all.  Voters in fact tend to favor the kind of posts that doesn't take them a long time to read.  And make it easy to still get to the vote buttons when they reached the end of the post :)

Best thing to do when you want to take the time to write a detailed answer is to cater to *both* kind of readers.  Start your post with a summary that doesn't take more than a minute or two to read.  That will keep the casual reader happy.  *Then* go into deeper detail, that will keep the interested reader happy.

Comment: I see this in practice every time at all the questions I ask. Users with a lot of reputation start small, answer the main questions by small statements, then do incremental development just like they are probably used to to improve the answer in depth and clarity.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add a better or clearer answer or explain some other explanation to a question then please write your answer. It may help the original asker of the question, it may also help later readers with similar questions.

It would appear that the asker of the question thought the answer by Vikas provided what they wanted to know, hence they accepted that answer. Your answer adds some extra insight. Over time others may read the question and all the answers and vote those they find useful or helpful.

As I write these notes the question is only 13 hours old. It was asked just at Christmas when a large part of the world is on holiday. So the number of people who might read the Q&A may be smaller than normal for the middle of a week.

The title of your question includes "*... should I be rewarded for that?*". Yes, you should be rewarded for a good answer to a useful questions but the Stackoverflow community decides whether your effort is useful and merits rewards. Asking for a reward may have the opposite effect.

Comment: If it is just a matter of time then yes I should be patient. I had assumed that it would be unlikely that the question would get attention. I certainly understand "Asking for a reward may have the opposite effect.". People that answer questions tend to not respond to manipulation. My question was promted by a general impression of this site that is frustrating.